# Can't understand why UDS length seem wrong to me

Tags: python, protocols, can-bus, diagnostics, automotive

I'm learning UDS and in the process I came across this data frame logged from a car

```
Tester,02 10 01 
Car.  ,10 18 50 01 AA AA AA AA  
Tester,30 00 00 .. FLOW CONTROL  
Car.  ,21 AA AA AA AA AA AA AA  
Car.  ,22 AA AA AA AA AA AA AA  
Car.  ,23 AA AA AA AA 00 00 00
```

What I don't understand is this:
The length in the tester frame is 2 followed by two bytes which is correct. Notice that the function and subfunction are counted in the length.
But in the tester the length is 18 but when I count the number of bytes (AA in my example) they are 22 bytes not including the positive response and subfunction if we include them it will become 24.
So does the length in ISO-TP only refer to the following frames not the first one? Because if we don't cound the first frame which had the position message then the length of AA bytes is 18.

Also, can someone guide me to a good library (preferrably in Python for now since I'm still in the learning process) that implements UDS since I'm just doing everything hardcoded and I don't like the mess that I end up with.

Comment: I don't know this protocol, but you do realize that all output on CAN is hex, yes? 18 hex = 24 dec.

Comment: Thank friend that's the result of not resting :D how dumb I am to not notice that

Answer (score 1):

The length in the messages is correct - it is calculated over the complete payload: including SID, Subfunction, etc., but excluding:

- the Length itself
- the Control Information (i.e. the Consecutive Frames counter)
- the Padding at the end (i.e. 0x00)

In a Single Frame the length takes only 1 Byte, while in the First Frame the length itself takes 12 Bit (hence occupying 2 Bytes including the control information 0x1 to signalize the frame type as being a First Frame).

```
Car.  ,10 18 50 01 AA AA AA AA  
Tester,30 00 00 .. FLOW CONTROL  
Car.  ,21 AA AA AA AA AA AA AA  
Car.  ,22 AA AA AA AA AA AA AA  
Car.  ,23 AA AA AA AA 00 00 00
```

In your example the length of the First Frame is 0x18 - the first 2 Bytes of the First Frame (0x10, 0x18) do not count towards the length. So if you count the bytes starting with 0x50 and excluding the consecutive frame counters (0x21, 0x22, 0x23, ...):

```
      0x50, 0x01, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA,
0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA 
0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA 
0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA
```

there are exactly 24 Bytes (0x18 Bytes in hexadecimal).

In Python you can use the [udsoncan](https://udsoncan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) library to get a UDS services based  abstraction or [python-can-isotp](https://can-isotp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/isotp/examples.html) to just handle the transport layer for you.